# handle error when change domain name

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I want to handle 404 error when change the domain name, here's the domain name

http://localhost:8080/OnlineQuerySystemNew/

when I change any letter 404 error occurs even I make custom error page in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean "context name" when you said "domain name"? The context name is like the `OnlineQuerySystemNew` part in your example. The domain name is the `localhost` part in your example (which is actually not a real domain name, but you get the point).

The 404 error page in webapp's `web.xml` only applies to 404 errors in webapp's own context, not in other contexts. So it only kicks in when you do like http://localhost:8080/OnlineQuerySystemNew/peekaboo

To achieve your requirement, you need to deploy a `ROOT` webapp in Tomcat and put and configure the desired error page right there.